# How can i use a redirect code in html without <script>?

Tags: html, redirect

I want to use a redirect code but not use of JavaScript. I want to use in html 
only use of the tags

```
<a> <b> <i> <em> <strong> <address> <cite> <code> <ul> <ol> <li> <dl> <dt>
<dd> <small> <sup> <sub> <blockquote> <h1> <h2> <h3> <h4> <h5> <h6> <pre>
<img> <br> <br /> <hr> <p> <div> <span> <embed> <object> <table> <tr>
<td> <iframe>
```

Please can any one tell me how can i use any of tag that i mentioned above for redirect code.

Answer (score 1):

It's not one of the tags you listed (and you can't do this with any of the tags you listed), but you could look at using `meta refresh`:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://somesite.com/'" />
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20140311/H76

Comment: thannks Ant P but its only use in meta. i want that in body.

Comment: Then you can't do it without either using JavaScript or returning a redirect code from the server.